# How can I copy a python function's signature and define a new function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to copy a function's signature to define a new function that extends it. Python 3.4, if the version matters to the solution.

In `ham.py`:

```
def spam(pork *, salt, taste=False):
    """External function I don't control."""
    return food
```

In `eggs.py`:

```
import ham

def breakfast(pork, *, drama, salt, taste=False):
    """The function I want to define, done statically."""
    return eggs, ham.spam(pork=pork, salt=salt, taste=taste)
```

I would like to define `breakfast` so that if the user has a different-but-compatible version of `ham.py` installed, the `breakfast` function will include any changes to the arguments in `ham.spam`.

Ex:

```
# Probably not how you do this...
signature = inspect.Signature(breakfast)
breakfast = types.FunctionType(
    how-do-i-make-a-multi-line-code-object, 
    what-do-i-use-for-globals,
    name='breakfast', 
    argdefs=from-signature)
```

Comment: Does `breakfast` do anything with its arguments other than passing them straight through to `spam`?

Comment: @jwodder no, the arguments are passed through directly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in parts, to get the signature you can use `inspect.getargspec` or `inspect.getfullargspec` from the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module

```
import inspect
fullArgSpec = inspect.getfullargspec(spam)
```

This returns

> FullArgSpec(args=['pork', 'salt', 'taste'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(False,), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

With this, you can build up the string of argument calls. First building up the postional args and then the keyword arguments. Crudely put, something like this

```
argumentsString = ""
for argument in itertools.chain(fullArgSpec.args, fullArgSpec.kwonlyargs):
    if argument in locals():
        argumentsString += '{}={},'.format(argument,locals()[argument])
```

Note, that this can fail if any of the positional arguments are missing. If needed you should add a check to cleanlly exit at this point.

To second part, where you want to build the function up, I was hoping to find something like [apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), but it seems to be deprecated. The reason for building the `argumentString` was to execute this using the [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to execute a call to `spam` with the built argument string matching a normal function call

```
exec('spam({})'.format(argumentsString))
```

The string passed to exec is

> spam(pork=2,salt=3)

Comment: Please note that `exec` is not necessary and is generally a bad idea. If you have a list (or rather, an iterable) of positional arguments, and a dictionary of keyword arguments, you can call `spam` with `spam(*args, **kwargs)` where `args` and `kwargs` are the `list` and `dict`, respectively. This is a lot safer than using `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

This example expands a functions (`fct_expand_args`) arguments by the arguments of another function (`fct`).

```py
import inspect

def fct(a, b=1):
    print(a, b)
    
def fct_expand_args(*args, **kwargs):
    full_arg_spec = inspect.getfullargspec(fct)
    for kw, arg in zip(full_arg_spec.args, args):
        kwargs.update({kw: arg})
    print(kwargs)
    
fct_expand_args(1, 2, c=3)  # {'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
fct_expand_args(1, b=2, c=3)  # {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
fct_expand_args(1, d=2, c=3)  # {'d': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
fct_expand_args(e=1, d=2, c=3)  # {'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'c': 3}
```